# Map 'Jump to mark line' to 'Jump to mark position'

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Let's say I've set a mark **a** via <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. Then <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> will bring me to the first non whitespace character of the line. However <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>  will bring me to the exact position of the mark **a**.

I prefer the second behaviour and would like to create a map. So I always get the behaviour of the backtick command.

**First attempt:**

```
:map 'a `a
:map 'b `b
... etc
```

It seems really bad to do this for every possible mark. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'a
```

is a sentence: "jump to *the line where mark `a` is*".

```
`a
```

is also a sentence: "jump to *where mark `a` is*".

Since you want *"the line where a given mark is"* to mean *"where the given mark is"*, mapping all the possible sentences would certainly be wasteful.

Instead, you only need to swap those two elements:

```
nnoremap ' `
```

which reads: *"the line where a given mark is* now means *where the given mark is".*

Comment: Won't this replace ' with ` outside the context of marks as well?

Comment: It will only affect normal mode. Insert mode and command line will be unaffected. This is the difference between `nnoremap` and `noremap`. And as far as I know in normal mode ' and ` are pretty much just used for marks.

Comment: @Tumbler41 Thank you :) That's what I wanted to hear!