# how to remap backtick mark with single-quote mark globally

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions, mark

I want to swap `'` with `` ` `` for all combinations of commands in normal mode.
I have tried the following:

```
nnoremap ' `
nnoremap ` '
```

It works for commands like `''`, ``` `` ```, but failed for `d''`, `y''`, etc.

related question:
[Map 'Jump to mark line' to 'Jump to mark position'](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9591/map-jump-to-mark-line-to-jump-to-mark-position)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `nnoremap` which means the mapping will only work in normal mode. `d` and `y` leave you in operator pending mode. Adding the following should solve these cases:

```
onoremap ' `
onoremap ` '
```

I'm not entirely sure whether this will have any undesired side effects though.

Comment: thank you, these solved my problem:
onoremap ' `
onoremap ` '
nnoremap ' `
nnoremap ` '
vnoremap ' `
vnoremap ` '

Comment: If you also want to remap in visual mode you might consider using `noremap` which maps normal, visual, select and operator-pending modes.